# texstudio opens but only with minimised window i can't access

Tags: texstudio

texstudio seems to open but the window is minimised and I can't get it to open. i have uninstalled and reinstalled latest version texstudio 4.5.2. I'm stuck. no idea what the problem is. Can anyone help please? thanks. See image[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Maybe https://superuser.com/questions/477095/recover-windows-opening-off-screen/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. I uninstalled version 4.5.2 and reinstalled version 4.5.1 which gave the same problem. I then renamed the `texstudio.ini` file to `texstudio~.ini` (found in `%AppData%`) and the problem was sorted.